# Why the Firebase returns an array instead of a dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application I use firebase, I save the main user data in rows and mene important (characteristic) in the dictionary. The user can add, modify and delete data. Several times I get successful data from the database, but then for some reason I get a dictionary instead of an array. Moreover, this array contains objects NSNull application and falls. Here's the code I retrieve data:

```
[self.ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

TSFireUser *user = [[TSFireUser alloc] init];

NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"];
FIRUser *fireUser = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;


NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataBase/users/%@/userData", fireUser.uid];
NSString *keyToParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataBase/users/%@", fireUser.uid];

FIRDataSnapshot *fireUser = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath:key];
FIRDataSnapshot *fireUserParameters = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath:keyToParameters];

FIRDataSnapshot *userIdent = fireUser.value[@"userID"];
FIRDataSnapshot *userName = fireUser.value[@"displayName"];
FIRDataSnapshot *userEmail = fireUser.value[@"email"];
FIRDataSnapshot *userPhoto = fireUser.value[@"photoURL"];
FIRDataSnapshot *dateOfBirth = fireUser.value[@"dateOfBirth"];
FIRDataSnapshot *location = fireUser.value[@"location"];
FIRDataSnapshot *gender = fireUser.value[@"gender"];
FIRDataSnapshot *parameters = fireUserParameters.value[@"parameters"];


user.uid = (NSString *)userIdent;
user.displayName = (NSString *)userName;
user.email = (NSString *)userEmail;
user.photoURL = (NSString *)userPhoto;
user.dateOfBirth = (NSString *)dateOfBirth;
user.location = (NSString *)location;
user.gender = (NSString *)gender;
user.parameters = (NSMutableDictionary *)parameters;}];
```

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

I alone decided the issue. The bottom line was that the keys to the data in the database were presented in line number @ "1", @ "2", @ "3" by adding the word "key" everything  was working well. As a result, the keys look something like this: @ "key1", @ "key2" @ "key3" ..